# flutter :: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed,

Tags: flutter, dart

```
E/flutter ( 7797): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myfilename/files/Audiorecords/' 
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I'm getting the above error, how do I fix it?

This is part of my code.

```
class FlutterAudioRecorder {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel("com.example.recorder_ttest");
  static const String DEFAULT_EXTENSION = '.m4a';
  static LocalFileSystem fs = LocalFileSystem();

  String? _path;
  String? _extension;
  Recording? _recording;
  String? _sampleRate;

  Future? _initRecorder;
  Future? get initialized => _initRecorder;
  Recording? get recording => _recording;

  FlutterAudioRecorder(String path, {AudioFormat? audioFormat, String sampleRate = "16000"}) {
    _initRecorder = _init(path, audioFormat, sampleRate);
  }
```

The part where my code is different from the original code is

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('flutter_audio_recorder2');  //original code
```

I think there is a problem with this part.
How can I find out where 'flutter_audio_recorder2' is defined in the original code?

Comment: check if `'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myfilename/files/Audiorecords/'` is exist.

Comment: What folder should I check to see if it exists? Any resources on how to find it?

Comment: check directory: `bool exists = await Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myfilename/files/Audiorecords/').exists();`

Comment: Thank you for answer! As a result of fixing the part where the problem occurred, true is printed. However, the following error occurs: E/flutter (17061): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel com.example.filename)

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException` usually happened when you adding a library but forgetting to hot restart or full restart the app.

Comment: if the directory is exist, then you have the problem when adding a file to it. Please add your related code with the problem on your question.

Comment: I edited my post! Can you please check my post again?

Comment: You need to use the same channel name with your android and ios platform implementation, see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels. The `flutter_audio_recorder2` name is inside your android or ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not with the MethodChannel, the error FileSystemException indicates that it cannot find the path `'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myfilename/files/Audiorecords/'`. Verify if the path/directory exists.